NET8.0 WebApi project post build event does not execute as desired
I have Web Api project as back-end and Blazor WebAssembly as front-end. I want copy Blazor publish files to Web Api publish subdirectory wwwroot and then zip all files. I added post build instructions to Web Api project file but nothing happens - files are not copied and zip file is not created. In Output window I see coping and zip operations (i.e. looks like all fine). Here is my setup:
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BlazorWasmProjectPath>..\Online.Shop.ClientBlazorWasm</BlazorWasmProjectPath>
        <BlazorWasmPublishDir>$(BlazorWasmProjectPath)\bin\$(Configuration)\net8.0\browser-wasm\publish</BlazorWasmPublishDir>
        <BlazorWasmwwwrootDir>$(BlazorWasmPublishDir)\wwwroot</BlazorWasmwwwrootDir>
        <!-- We have explicitly define the project publish directory instead of using PublishDir.
             PublishDir contains "Online.Shop.WebApi\obj\Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\*" -->
        <WebApiPublishDir>$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\net8.0\Publish</WebApiPublishDir>
        <WebApiwwwrootDir>$(WebApiPublishDir)\wwwroot</WebApiwwwrootDir>
        <DateTimeStamp>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_-_HH_mm_ss"))</DateTimeStamp>
        <ZipFileName>$(WebApiPublishDir)\OnlineShopDeploy_$(DateTimeStamp).zip</ZipFileName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Publish Blazor WebAssembly project -->
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish $(BlazorWasmProjectPath) -c $(Configuration) -o $(BlazorWasmPublishDir)" />

    <!-- Create the destination directory if it does not exist -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(WebApiwwwrootDir)" />


    <!-- Copy Blazor WebAssembly files to wwwroot of the Web API publish directory -->
    <Exec Command="xcopy /E /I /Y &quot;$(BlazorWasmwwwrootDir)\&quot; &quot;$(WebApiwwwrootDir)\&quot;" />

    <!-- Create a zip file of the publish directory -->
    <Exec Command="powershell Compress-Archive -Path &quot;$(WebApiPublishDir)\*&quot; -DestinationPath &quot;$(ZipFileName)&quot;" />
</Target>

Please help.

Why not create a working PS/bat file and then just execute that file?

Your "PostBuild" target runs after Publish, so it's really a "post publish" target. Is that what you wanted?

Yes, after Web Api publish I want publish and copy Blazor files.
